# How to check if HDFS file contains binary data or not?

Tags: file, hadoop, hdfs

Is there any tool or utility to check if HDFS files are `textfile` or binary files like `avro`, `ORC`, etc.?

I can't reply on file extensions. I don't want to know exact type. I just need to know if data is **readable** or not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's `bash` it

```
 hdfs dfs -cat /file/on/hdfs | head -15 > tmp ; file -i tmp ; rm tmp
```

For unreadable files like `parquet` etc. you'll get this:

```
tmp: application/octet-stream; charset=binary
```

Comment: @dev ツ  `tmp: text-plain; charset=ascii` I just got this for a TXT file. Not that it matters, but which version are you on?

Comment: its working fine with text data having , or tab as delimiter. But my text data is delimited by **CTRL^A** (_default hive delimiter_). It's returning `tmp: application/octet-stream; charset=binary` in this case.

Comment: Well technically, that is a non-printable character.

Comment: I agree with you

Comment: your answer works fine as per the need mentioned in the question